# Memoryless property of probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Trucks arrive at the station on a given highway according to a Poisson process with $\lambda$ = 0.1/minute. This means that after a truck is just passed, the time for the next truck to arrive is an exponential random number with an average arrival time of 10 minutes. Your car just broke on this highway, and you are waiting for the next truck for hitchhiking; what is your expected waiting time? On average, how many minutes ago was the last truck left?

By the memorylessness property of exponential distributions, we can say that the average waiting time is 10 minutes. But what exactly is the memorylessness property? Can I get an intuitive understanding of the same?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have already waited for $5$ minutes ($t=5$). The memorylessness property means that the probability of the bus arriving in the next minute remains the same as before, i.e., $0.09516...\approx0.1$. The fact that you have already waited for 5 minutes does not affect the future probability of the bus arriving in the next minute.

Comment: What if the time difference followed a normal distribution? Would it be solvable in that case?

Comment: That would imply existence (non-zero probability) of negative waiting times. If you had some *arbitrary* probability distribution which governed the inter-event times of a point process $(T_1,T_2,\cdots)$ (permitting $T_k<0$) the parametrised distribution can nevertheless be estimated from that sequence (a sample)

Answer (score 0):

**Memory-less Properties of Coin Flip**

Let's say that we have an unfair coin that yields tail with probability of $p$. We know that the number of tails follow the binomial distribution:

$$
B(x;n,p) = \binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}
$$

No matter what had happened in the past, the probability to get tail in the next toss is still $p$ and the expected number of tails in the next $n$ tosses is still $np$. Hopefully, it's clear now that the binomial distribution is memory-less.

**Poisson Distribution as Limit**

Now let's say that we divide one minute into so many small intervals $1/n$. In each interval, the probability that a truck arrive is equal and independent; $\lambda/n$. The number of trucks arrival in the next $t$ minutes follows the following binomial distribution:

$$
B\left(x;nt,\frac{\lambda}{n}\right) = \binom{nt}{x}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{x}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{nt-x}
$$

As we have established before, this distribution (binomial) is memory-less. Now let's see what happens when the interval becomes smaller and smaller i.e. the number of intervals becomes large but at the same time the probability that truck arrives in an interval becomes small:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{nt}{x}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{x}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{nt-x}
=
\frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^{x}e^{-\lambda t}}{x!}
$$

This is the Poisson distribution. Turns out, Poisson distribution is the limit of binomial distribution as the number of experiments becomes infinitely large while at the same time the probability of occurrence becomes infinitely small. Remember the memory-less properties of binomial distribution?

As a bonus, the expected value of random variables that follow binomial distribution is $n\cdot p$. In the same fashion, the expected value of random variables that follow Poisson distribution is $nm\cdot\frac{\lambda}{n}=\lambda m$. This is why $\lambda$ is called the rate of occurrence.

**Exponential Distribution**

By definition, if the number of truck arrivals follows Poisson distribution, the time until a truck arrive is a random variable that follows exponential distribution. Its cumulative density function is given below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(t) &= 1 - P\left(X=0;\lambda t\right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^{0}e^{-\lambda t}}{0!}\\
&= 1 - e^{-\lambda t}
\end{aligned}
$$

and its probability density function

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}F(t) \\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda t}
\end{aligned}
$$

The truck arrival is a memory-less process, whatever had happened in the past does not have any effect on the time until the next truck arrives i.e. the exponential distribution is memory-less.

**Remark**

There is another distribution that is closely related to Poisson distribution, which is the Gamma distribution. But that's a story for another day I guess.